# All distributions of items between buckets

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I recently ran into a problem where I need to figure out how to distribute items into buckets but I need to find all the ways to distribute them.

the input comes in as an array of integers that tell you the maximum each column can hold and there must be N amount of items in the array.

for example:

```
maxItems = 3
maximums = [4,2,1] # The order of maximums DOES matter meaning
# This means that the results of maximums = [2,4,1] are different from maximums = [1,2,4]
outputs = [[3,0,0],[2,1,0],[1,1,1],[2,0,1],[0,2,1]] # results are in no particular order
# notice how the sum of each result is equal to maxItems and each value in each of the rows are less than the value inside of maximums
```

I attempted to solve this problem in javascript but I am unable to figure out how to approach this problem. I wanted to start off by filling the first columns with as many numbers as possible and start moving to the right, but as the maximums array gets bigger, this method gets more inaccurate and I don't exactly know how to approach it at all.

If you have any more questions please feel free to ask if you dont understand the problem.

The code I started off with in javascript was

```
var all_combinations = function(N, maximums){
    var empty = maximums.map(function(){return 0;}); // create empty array size of maximums filled with 0s
    var s = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < empty.length && s < N;){
        if (empty[i] >= maximums[i]){i++;continue;}
        empty[i]++;
        s++;
    } // fill the left side with as many items as possible

    // Then i would proceed to move one item at a time to the right side but some how i would need to do it for the whole array and this is where I get stuck.
};
```

I tried searching up this problem, but I never found out how to do it the way it was set up here. I tried finding similar problems but they were always unrelated to this. Maybe I am searching up the problem wrong. If someone can link a helpful resource that would be great.

If you have any questions please ask them. I will answer to the best of my abilities.

Comment: am I missing some information to make this an acceptable question? Already one close vote and it's not even 5 minutes

Comment: No, you're not. I personally disagree with voting to close this, it's just this is a somewhat computer science heavy question, and most questions on SO are simple "please help fix my program" sort of deals, so this one will take a little longer to answer. No worries though, you're in the right place and I think it's a well thought out question.

Comment: If I understand you, you want to find all possible permutations within the boundary defined by `maximums` and group them by the size defined by `maxItems` or `N`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I believe the sum of all the values in each permutation must equal `maxItems` / `N`

Comment: @Patrick Roberts that is also correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy to understand recursive solution with ECMA 6 generators:

for each `i`, place `i` items into the first slot if they fit, then distribute the others among the rest.

```js
function* bucket_distributions(capacities,nItems){
    if (capacities.length==1) {
      if (capacities[0] >= nItems)
        yield [nItems];
    }
    else if (capacities.length>1) {
      for (var i=Math.min(capacities[0],nItems);i>=0;i--) {
        for (subdist of
            bucket_distributions(capacities.slice(1),nItems-i))
          yield [i].concat(subdist);
      }
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(bucket_distributions([4,2,1],3)))
```

Comment: That is a pretty neat  solution. I didnt think javascript for..of yet XD

Comment: I ended up using your solution cuz it was easily convertable to python.

Comment: @ahitt6345 Since I have a Python background, I actually converted it vice versa for the answer :-)

Comment: You should not be nesting if statements.

Comment: @Arrow the `else if` relates solely to the outer `if`, not the inner one, so I had no other (obvious) options but to nest them. The idea is for the generator to return nothing at all in other cases, making the `for..of` loop a no-op.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a recursive approach with checking all parts of the constraints.

It works with an index and a temporary array for keeping the count of the items.

At start, the index is zero and the array is empty. With the call of `fork`, the first exit option is checked, which means the constraints are checked and if greater or equal count, then the recursion stops.

The second exit option is when the sum of the items reaches the wanted count, then the temporary array is pushed to the result set and the recursion ends.

In all other cases, `fork` is called again with either

- same index `i` and an incremented value of the temporary array at the index, or
- incremented index and the actual temporary array.

```js
function getCombination(max, count) {

    function fork(index, temp) {
        var sum = temp.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        if (max.some((a, i) => (temp[i] || 0) > a) || index === max.length || sum > count) {
            return;
        }
        if (sum === count) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        fork(index, max.map((a, i) => (temp[i] || 0) + (i === index)));
        fork(index + 1, temp);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombination([4, 2, 1], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An iterative approach with a previous check if the sum plus value is smaller or equal than the wanted count.

```js
function getCombination(max, count) {

    function iter(index, sum, temp) {
        var i;
        if (count === sum) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        for (i = max[index]; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (sum + i <= count) {
                iter(index + 1, sum + i, temp.concat(i));
            }
        }
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, 0, []);
    return result;
}

console.log(getCombination([4, 2, 1], 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The answer does do what I want it to do. But how does it work? Some of the functionality of this is unclear to me. I guess ill figure it out on the documentation.

Comment: Could use some explanation. ["Try this" answers have zero educational value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) and nondescriptive var names do not help understanding the algorithm, either.

Comment: E.g. I suspect it tries all combinations and filters out those that exceed limits, i.e. lots of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a well-commented iterative solution with an interactive demo:

```js
// reducer function for calculating sum of array
function sum(prev, next) {
  return prev + next;
}

// returns the contextual constraints of a bucket
function bucketMinMax(maxItems, otherItems, bucketMax) {
  return {
    // minimum values in bucket to meet maxItems
    min: Math.max(0, maxItems - otherItems),
    // maximum values in bucket to meet maxItems
    max: Math.min(maxItems, bucketMax),
  };
}

// takes an incomplete combination and expands it with the next bucket 
// starting from the left
function expandCombination(maxItems, maximums, combinations) {
  // get next combo group to expand
  var comboGroup = combinations.shift();
  // get index of expansion bucket
  var index = comboGroup.length;
  // calculate maximum possible otherItems
  var otherItems = maximums.slice(index + 1).reduce(sum, 0);

  // removes already used spaces from maxItems in combination group being expanded
  maxItems -= comboGroup.reduce(sum, 0);

  // get constraints for expansion bucket
  var {min, max} = bucketMinMax(maxItems, otherItems, maximums[index]);

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    // add combo group expansions to output
    combinations.push(comboGroup.concat([i]));
  }
}

// main function
function allCombinations(maxItems, maximums) {
  // will eventually contain all combinations
  var output = [[]];

  // loops through array of combinations, expanding each one iteratively
  while (output.length > 0 && output[0].length < maximums.length) {
    // takes incomplete combination group and expands it with possible values
    // for next bucket starting from the left
    expandCombination(maxItems, maximums, output);
  }

  return output;
}

document.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var maxes = JSON.parse(maximums.value);
  var items = JSON.parse(maxItems.value);
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(allCombinations(items, maxes)));
});

document.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<label>maxItems
<input id="maxItems" value="3">
</label>
<label>maximums
<input id="maximums" value="[4,2,1]">
</label>
```